# Android sql column does not exist

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I try to create a table and insert some values but it gives an error and says there is no such kolomn. To me, it looks like I´m creating the table right.
What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I changed the code t the code above, but I am still facing the same problem. I commented cv.put(colEnd, "Sales"); and the error is gone. So it seems that the problem is in creating the tabel. Any other ideas?

This is my code:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
static final String dbName="workObjectsDB";
static final String workTable="WorkObjects";
static final String colID="WorkObjectID";
static final String colStart="StartTime";
static final String colEnd="EndTime";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, dbName, null,33); 
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+workTable+" (" +colID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " +colStart+ " TEXT, "+colEnd+ " TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+workTable);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void insertSome(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

    cv.put(colStart, "Sales");
    cv.put(colEnd, "Sales");
    db.insert(workTable, colID, cv);

    db.close();
}

public Cursor getAll(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT * from "+workTable,new String [] {});

    return cur;
}
}
```

Log:

> 11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103): Error inserting EndTime=Sales StartTime=Sales
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table WorkObjects has no column named EndTime: , while compiling: INSERT INTO WorkObjects(EndTime,StartTime) VALUES (?,?)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.acquireAndLock(SQLiteStatement.java:260)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:112)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1807)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1680)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at robin.urenapp.DatabaseHelper.insertSome(DatabaseHelper.java:39)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at robin.urenapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4531)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   11-27 16:25:14.765: E/SQLiteDatabase(7103):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it should be:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+workTable+" (" +colID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " +colStart+ " TEXT, "+colEnd+ " TEXT)");
```

But after fixing it, I had to upgrade the database from 33 to 34.

Answer (score 2):

According to [SQLite data types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), `STRING` does not seem to be a valid data type.

So change:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+workTable+" (" +colID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " +colStart+ " STRING, "+colEnd+ "STRING)");
```

to (notice I put an extra spacing after `colEnd`):

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+workTable+" (" +colID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " +colStart+ " TEXT, "+colEnd+ " TEXT)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `STRING` for the column data type; SQLite does not support `STRING` it supports `TEXT`. Change `STRING` to `TEXT`. Also note you need to add a space here `+colEnd+ " STRING)` like the other guys noted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,  whenever u are assigning any value as primary key use underscore before column name so do
from this
colId="WorkObjectID“
To this
colId="_workObjectID“

and change from STRING to TEXT